# What is texlive.tlpdb and how to fix its missing?

Tags: texlive

A friend of mine installed TeX Live 2020 but get error when running `texdoc amsmath`:

```
$ texdoc amsmath
texdoc error: No texlive.tlpdb nor shipped tlpdb data found.
```

Searching on Google doesn't help, so I post this question here.

BTW, I found `/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb` on CTAN root, but I do not know how it can help my friend.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Here is the installation procedure:

- Download texlive2020 distribution from Tsinghua University mirror repository.
- Then, `sudo ./install.sh` and wait for the installation to complete
- After installation, import latex into the system path to compile `.tex` file in terminal.

After the installation is complete, the texdoc command has no problems. It was just suddenly discovered that it could not be used a few days later.

No config files have been deleted.

Comment: tlpdb stands for (I think:-)  tex live package data base, it is the main control file for the texlive package installation, it lists every package in texlive and whether you have it installed or not, which texlive mirror repository you use and lots of other details. The texlive installation seems broken if it is not there.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle , every time I ask a question, you are there waiting for me. lol. So it comes to be the next question: is there any solution to fix this? What if I download it from CTAN and place it in the folder `TEXMFDIST/tlpkg`?

Comment: It's impossible to guess how you got in that position, the file on ctan is no use, the file is a _local_ file that records which packages are installed _on that machine_ it should be `/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`  if your texlive tree starts at  `/usr/local/texlive/2020` but don't edit it by hand or you will completely confuse the texlive package manager.  What exactly did your friend install. vanilla texlive from TUG or a linux distribution texlive ? (not all of which use tlmgr I believe)

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same problem when updating from MacOS 10.14 to 10.15.  It turned out that I had to upgrade MacPorts as a result, and when doing so, MacPorts put /opt/local/bin in the front of the PATH, so the wrong version of texdoc was called.  No idea if that's any help for you, but you could try running `which texdoc` to check that you are running the texdoc that you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a guix installation of texlive on linux.
This is how I fixed it:

- `locate texlive.tlpdb`
- copy it to my local texmf tree: `cp $(locate texlive.tlpdb) ~/texmf/`
- create a texdoc directory there: `mkdir ~/texmf/texdoc`
- copy the texdoc config file there: `cp $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFDIST)/texdoc/texdoc.cnf ~/texmf/texdoc/`
- edit `texdoc.cnf` and add the following line: `texlive_tlpdb = ~/texmf/texlive.tlpdb`

It now seems to work fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I have installed texlive with pamac from Manjaro's extra repo and I have no texlive.tlpdb in my system.